# Sharing routes and controllers between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core projects in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

**Question**: How do I configure a solution with a .NET Core application to use the same controllers, routes, and authentication handled by an ASP.NET application in the same solution?

**Background**: I have a project that is a single page application built with the ASP.NET Single Page Application template included in VS. The template creates a project using knockout as the SPA library. I am going to greatly expand the codebase of the application and we are going to move it to an Angular project.

I'd like to use the new Angular template that properly takes advantage of the Angular CLI as well as uses the more lightweight .NET Core. The problem is that I dont know how to take advantage of all the backend codebase currently maintained in the original ASP.NET application from the .NET Core project in the same solution.

I am able to develop the Angular application within the original ASP.NET application by creating a ClientApp directory and building a new Angular CLI application in that directory. I develop using the `ng build --watch` command which outputs static files on every save to a ClientDist directory. I can then serve up the rendered static assets from any given route by adding a few adjustments to my web.confg and calling the following in the associated controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new FilePathResult("/ClientDist/index.html", "text/html");
    }
```

The major downside to this approach is:

1. I believe it muddles concerns of the codebase. An Angular CLI application is a very large undertaking that should be seperate from the rest of the backend codebase as much as possible.
2. (the real downside) I cant figure out how to debug my Typescript files in the browser. Normally when you develop an Angular CLI app you can set breakpoints in the compiled code thats then mapped to the original Typescript file. With this model I only have the compiled code. Its doable right now since its a small application, but it'll hamstring us latter.

Comment: You are asking about extremely different stuff that by their own most is too broad for this site. Your title is barely even mentioned in the question  at the top. Please read [ask]. As an extra, there's no easy way to handle all of this

Comment: This feels like 3 questions in one. The actual posted answer is pretty accurate in terms of the stated question. Your other two really have nothing to do with .NET Core vs ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a large project that consists of some legacy code (ASP.NET MVC), some SPA (React in my case), some newer Web API backend (ASP.NET Core), and here's how I've evolved in my journey:

1. Develop your SPA entirely outside of your .NET solution. This liberates you to use more Typescript + Javascript savvy IDEs (VS Code in my case), debug them with the tooling provided by your framework (Angular, React, etc.), and take advantage of more advanced client-side debugging mechanisms built into Chrome, and even some IDEs (again, VS Code does an excellent job debugging client-side Javascript via its Chrome debugging interface integration). Caveat: you'll have to invent a bit of a **debug-build-deploy** workflow to string together debug-time hot-reload capabilities, build-time bundling and minifying, publish-time copying of assets, etc.
2. If you're in the process of moving your backend from an ASP.NET codebase to the ASP.NET Core codebase, start by having your client call two different end-points (one running your legacy backend hosting legacy APIs, the other running your new backend). Then, incrementally port code into your new codebase and evolve your client to call the new backend for the APIs that you've ported. Eventually, sunset your legacy backend once all APIs are ported. In the meantime, you may also have to proxy some backend calls from your ASP.NET Core codebase to your legacy ASP.NET codebase.
3. Finally, and I say this deliberately, if your client-side application is going to be an SPA, do consider Node JS for your backend.

This is where my journey has taken me so far. I consistently found the Big VS lacking in features and tooling when it came to client-side Javascript coding and debugging, whereas VS Code is a leading IDE for just this sort of work. Hence, my motivation to move my client-side development work entirely out of my VS solution.

Finally, I'm using Typescript for both the client-side SPA, as well as for my new Node JS backend. I can't imagine coding a big JS project without Typescript. But with it, I'm developing both our React frontend as well as our Node JS backend confidently and with ease. No more duplicate object interface/class definitions, redundant DTOs, etc. Things just meld together more nicely and coherently. And I'm saying this as a fan and long-time ASP.NET + Core developer, so no ideological motivations here, just practical reasoning.